# Version error difference between mysql and mysqldump?

Tags: mysql, terminal, redmine

Now I have problem that,

I direct terminal to get Redmine's backup files,
so My mac's terminal says that

```
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'gtid\_mode'': Native table 'performance_schema'.'session_variables' has the wrong structure (1682)
```

Mysql version are

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.14, for osx10.10 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

$mysqldump --version
mysqldump  Ver 10.13 Distrib 5.7.14, for osx10.10 (x86_64)
```

I can't know how to through the process...

please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is most likely due to Global Transaction Identifiers (GTIDs) introduced in MySQL 5.6. GTIDs which are used for replication across a master-slave topology.

Try adding

```
--set-gtid-purged=OFF
```

At the end of your mysqldump command.

Comment: Thanks ! I 'll try it !